# RxJS bind Observable

Tags: reactive-programming, rxjs

I'm having trouble with binding the result of observable A to a stream-observable B, such that:

```
Rx.Observable.concat(
  A,
  A.bind(valuesInA =>
    B.scan((acc, value) => {
      acc.push(value);
      return acc;
    }, valuesInA)))
```

So for example, if this is the case:

```
A: { onNext:[monkey], onComplete }
B: { onNext:banana, onNext:tree, onNext: ... }
```

I would like to get the observable:

```
AB: { onNext:[monkey],
      onNext:[monkey, banana],
      onNext:[monkey,banana,tree],
      onNext: ... }
```

If there was a bind operator, and it called its callback when its callee was done, that would be great, because A finishes rather quickly (initial load of values) and then B streams the rest of them.

How do I compose this?

---

```
Notes: B.scan( ... ) : Observable<Array<apeness>> so I need to subscribe its result
```

Comment: I found https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/core/operators/flatmapobserver.md which is similar in that I can return an Observable, but it's just not what I'd call `bind`... Is there a good answer to this that's not flatmapobserver?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Flatmap`, `scan`, and `startWith`:

```
A.flatMap(a => B.scan((acc,v) => acc.concat(v), a).startWith(a))
 .subscribe(...);
```